# In how many ways can you draw 3 balls?

Tags: combinatorics

The are $5$ identical white balls and $2$ identical black balls in the box. In how many ways can you draw $1$ black and $2$ white balls?

Comment: Could you give us some idea of where you are stuck with this? Also. is it homework?

Comment: It's the question from an old graduation exam.

Comment: As the answers show, the question is unclearly formulated. If all five white balls are "identical" (which is course is not really possible, or there would be only one of them), then different ways to choose two balls from them should not be distinguished, so how should one count those ways? Some answers below do distinguish the balls for counting purposes, another answer only looks at the order in which colours are drawn (which is a reasonable interpretation as well, but the numbers of balls now play no role).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen As I said, it's question from the graduation exam. There is no further explanation of what exactly the author wants to know. If you think about it, there are more possible interpretations. I posted it here to see if there is "the correct one". I suppose the author expected us to simply use the basic combinatorics rules, but it's not very clear.

Comment: If the author wanted you "to simply use the basic combinatorics rules" then she should have described the situation more clearly. Notably, if the answer should be $20$, then the word "identical" should be removed from the question (twice). Use of that word typically means that configurations that only differ by a permutation of those "identical" objects should be counted as one and the same. Here the result then would be that there is only one way to draw those balls.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I completely agree with you. Well, at least now I know, how did they get their "correct" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two black balls, and we want to choose one: $\dbinom 21 = 2$.

There are five white balls from which we want to draw two: $\dbinom 52 = \dfrac{5!}{2!\,3!} = \dfrac{5\cdot 4}{2} = 10$..

We use the *[rule of the product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)* (multiplying) to obtain the total number of ways of choosing one black ball and two white balls:

That gives us $$\binom 21 \cdot \binom 52 = 2\cdot \dfrac{5!}{2!3!} = 2\cdot \dfrac{5\cdot 4}{2} = 20$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you draw three balls from the box without replacement there are 3 options:

WWB, WBW and BWW since the balls are identical we don't care which black ball is which, or which white ball but if we did care we have

$5 \times 4 \times 2 + 5 \times 2 \times 4 + 2 \times 5 \times 4 = 40 + 40 + 40 = 120$

Ways of drawing these balls.

For the answer you have of 20 the questioner may not care about the order in which the balls are drawn only which balls

For the Black ball there are only 2 possibilities and for the White balls there are $5 \times 4 = 20$ ways these can be drawn but we don't care about the order so $\frac{5 \times 4}{2!} = 10$ ways.

Making a total of $2 \times 10 = 20$

It depends on your interpretation of what's meant by the number of ways: Do you only care about which balls or is the order in which they are drawn important.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I was told the answer is 20.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment on your reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

You choose the black and white balls independently from each set.  For each set of black balls, you have all the choices of white balls, so you multiply.

Comment: All the balls are in the same box.